# Cassandra vs Hbase for Conversation messages

Tags: java, email, cassandra, hbase

In my application, I need to save data of messages in any one of the big data model. I need to choose between the two.

I will explain below my usecase.

In my application, for every user emails will come. If the same email has been replied/forwarded we will form those set of replied/forwarded emails as conversation.

I planned to save content of the emails either in the cassandra or Hbase as follow.

Lets say user as U1 , messages as M1, conversations as C1.

Below is the flat-wide Row Model:

```
row key ->  U1
Column family(Composite key) -> C1#M1 or C1#M2 ...   (Conversation-ID#Message-ID) #->Separator
Column value  -> Content of M1 or Content of M2 .....
```

Below is the Tall-Narrow row model

```
row key ->  U1#C1  (User-ID#Conversation-ID) #->Separator
    Column family(Composite key) -> M1 or M2 or M3 ...   
    Column value  -> Content of M1 or Content of M2 .....
```

Which data-model is suitable for the usecase?

The following type of queries are executed over database.
1. to get content of all the mails of the conversation-Id C1 for the user U1. (may be ranges like 1 to 10 mails or 11 to 20 mails)
or
2. to get content of the particular mail M3 in conversation-ID C2 for the user U1.

The content of the messages will be vary from 10kb to 1MB. Rarely it'll go upto 10MB.(0.0001%) Mostly in Kbs.

In this system, read,insert/update/delete operations will be 80:20 . (80% Read Operations and 19% insert operations. Max 1% delete or Update of the contents) Delete operations will be like to delete the whole conversation. Update will be like to update particular message content

Please provide solution that is the appropriate for the above requirement with explanation which will be helpful.

Comment: Cassandra use case is more about time series and gathering info from sensors because it is optimized for writes. I would go for Hbase because you need more reads, but all it will come to in the end is having a good model.

Comment: @Whitefret  If i'm going to store as Tall Narrow row , which is the best Cassandra or Hbase?

Comment: you detailed your R/W/U operations in pourcentage but you didn't say what's in them so I can't tell.  If you consider Tall Narrow, how do you get all messages from a conversation?

Comment: @Whitefret The column value will contain the content of the email. Which may vary from 10kb to 1 MB. Rarely go upto 10MB(0.00001%).   In Case of Tall-Narrow Row, as I explained in the post, I have made Row key as U1#C1  (User-ID#Conversation-ID) #->Separator.  Is it fine with Cassandra?

Comment: @Whitefret  I may avoid Hbase due to maintainence problem. But I want to know whether cassandra will scale in the performance for my data model. Or else I'll go with Hbase.

Comment: my question is for a conversation-ID, how do you know the users in it?

Comment: @Whitefret  Conversation-ID will be generated as unique-id for every user and User-id also unique across the system. When User u1 queries for conversation C1 , we need lookup for row key U1#C1 which returns set of columns belong to rowkey.

Comment: that I understood, what I ask is how do you find u2 in conversation C1?

Comment: @Whitefret  For the user U2, the conversation id will be different as CS1.  No two users will have same conversation-id in the system.  For User u2, to get conversation of CS1, we need to lookup for rowkey u2#CS1.  Also the user U1, there may be conversation ids as C1, C2, C3, etc..... But the user U2, will not have same conversation-id  in his account. User u2 has Conversation-id as CS1, CS2, CS3, etc....

Comment: I don't really get how it will work :/. With this schema, how do you know how participate to a discussion?

Comment: @Whitefret  No two users will have conversation between them. All the users have mutually exclusive conversations. Please clarify whether is this data-model will work with cassandra without any major issues?

Comment: The problem I see, is that you create a column family by Message, which is a bad idea. You could have one column family with message as attributes, but again you will create a column by message. So messages should be a row. Anyway, I don't think that Cassandra makes sense for this, because you want something which is more like a key/value store.